# How to update nested functions in ipdb?

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb, elpy

I'm running IPython3 in Emacs with Elpy and trying to edit nested functions on the fly. For example, I have the attached file open in one frame and IPython3 in the other. I send the buffer to IPython with `C-c C-y b`, switch to the IPython frame with `C-x o`.

```
import sys

def print_name():
    print ("Alice")

def name ():
    print_name()

def main(argv):
    print ("In main.")
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    name()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Now I run the code by typing `main(0)`.

```
In [1]: main(0)
In main.
> /Users/ayank/Documents/programming/python/bar.py(12)main()
     11     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 12     name()
     13
```

I get a debug prompt and do:

```
ipdb> name()
Alice
```

Now, I go back to the code window for `print_name()`, change `Alice` to `Bob`, and resend the function to IPython3 with `C-c C-y f`. I see the following appear in the IPython frame:

```
ipdb> def print_name():
 ...:     print ("Bob")
```

I go back to the IPython frame and type:

```
ipdb> name()
Alice
ipdb> print_name()
Bob
```

That's not right: both should print `Bob`. I can resend the entire buffer to IPython with `C-c C-y b`, but I get the same answer: `name()` always outputs `Alice`.

What's going on here? How do I update nested functions in IPython3 while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when execution hits the breakpoint, code typed at the `ipdb` prompt gets executed in the `main` namespace. Hence, the new `print_name()` is in the `main` namespace while `name()` continues to call `print_name()` in the `global` namespace.

The new `print_name()` can be added to the `global` namespace manually by typing `globals()['print_name'] = print_name`.

An example run of the code:

```
ayank@snorri$ ./foo.py
In main.
> /Users/ayank/Documents/programming/python/bar.py(13)main()
     12     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 13     name()
     14 
ipdb> print_name()
Alice
ipdb> name()
Alice
ipdb> def print_name(): print ("Bob")
ipdb> print_name()
Bob
ipdb> name()
Alice
ipdb> globals()["print_name"] = print_name
ipdb> name()
Bob
```